# What are accents in Xcompose?

Tags: debian, text-processing, compose-key

I have been trying to figure out this thing called XCompose. Apparently if I use it correctly, I can do things like writing é or any such letter easily but don't understand how it works:

I did do the first part in https://wiki.debian.org/XCompose

i.e.

```
$ cat .xsessionrc
xmodmap -e "keysym Super_L = Multi_key"
```

but do not understand what `<dead_tilde> <dead_grave> <dead_circumflex>` mean.

Are these keys which I need to map similar to what mapping I had to do in `.xsessionrc` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that if you map a compose key, you needn’t worry about dead keys.

`<dead_tilde>` etc. correspond to keys in the keymap which are “dead”, *i.e.* which don’t produce a character on their own but always combine with the next keystroke. For example, on French keyboards, there’s a <kbd>^</kbd> key to the right of <kbd>P</kbd> which allows you to produce “ê” etc., by pressing <kbd>^</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd>. These don’t need the compose key at all.

The compose key is used for mappings which start with `<Multi_key>` (look at `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose`), and those use “normal” keys; for example, `<Multi_key> <asciicircum> <e>` means that you press your compose key, then <kbd>^</kbd> (the non-dead variant), then `e`, to get “ê”.

The standard accent compose sequences use the following keys for typical accents:

- <kbd>,</kbd> for a cedilla;
- <kbd>`</kbd> for a grave accent;
- <kbd>'</kbd> for an acute accent;
- <kbd>^</kbd> for a circumflex accent;
- <kbd>"</kbd> for a diaeresis;
- <kbd>~</kbd> for a tilde.

There are many, many more combinations, look at the `Compose` file mentioned above for details.